# Layering sprites in pygame with an unorthodox character class?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

forewarning this is my first post on stackoverflow and if I've formatted this post incorrectly or I've been unclear I'm happy to hear your constructive criticism. Thank you for your understanding!! I'll do better next time!!

SO:
I'm trying to create a game where my character runs around on the screen similar to Earthbound. I'm having trouble layering my sprites correctly. I would like my controlled character to appear behind other objects when he's "behind" them and appear in front when he's "in front".

I've looked through a lot of posts regarding sprite layering and I've found some useful information on the LayeredUpdates group as well as simply drawing images in a 'painters perspective' to create the illusion of depth in my game.

My problem probably lies in the way I've constructed my character classses..

```
def __init__(self,file_path,x,y,rate=3):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.rate=rate

    token_path = SpriteSheet('token.png')
    self.image = token_path.get_image(0,0,RECT_WIDTH,RECT_HEIGHT)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y+(48-RECT_HEIGHT)
```

I use a see-through token image as my rect object (for collision detection) and then blit all my pyganim animations to the screen based on my token rect position... like so:

```
def draw(self,surface):
    surface.blit(self.image,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y))
    if self.moveUp or self.moveDown or self.moveLeft or self.moveRight:
        self.moveConductor.play()
        if self.direction == UP:
            self.animObjs['walk_up'].blit(surface,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        if self.direction == DOWN:
            self.animObjs['walk_down'].blit(surface,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        etc.....
```

When I add these sprites to my groups, it doesn't add the actual animations, it adds the clear token so when it comes to layering I end up creating a nice stack of clear tokens instead of a layered sprite display.

My attempt at layering through drawing order works fine with one sprite in each group:

```
def layer(self,dudes,surface):
    for dude in dudes:
        if self.rect.bottom>dude.rect.y+5:
            dude.draw(surface)
            self.draw(surface)
        else:
            self.draw(surface)
            dude.draw(surface)
```

But when I add more sprites to my iterated group, they don't layer properly.

**Is there any way that I can implement a layering system with the way I've constructed my character classes?**

Here's my sprite.Group code in case it's relevent:

```
visibles = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
prot = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()

prot.add(nes)

visibles.add(aloysius)
visibles.add(bluecapboy)
visibles.add(applekid)
```

And here's my full Character code:

```
class Main_Character(pygame.sprite.DirtySprite):
layer=1
moveUp=moveDown=moveLeft=moveRight=False
moveUp_left=moveUp_right=moveDown_left=moveDown_right = False
direction = DOWN
animObjs={}

def __init__(self,file_path,x,y,rate=3):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.rate=rate

    token_path = SpriteSheet('token.png')
    self.image = token_path.get_image(0,0,RECT_WIDTH,RECT_HEIGHT)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y+(48-RECT_HEIGHT)

    path = SpriteSheet(file_path)

    self.down1 = pygame.transform.scale((path.get_image(0,0,16,24)),(32,48))
    self.down2 = pygame.transform.scale((path.get_image(16,0,16,24)),(32,48))
    self.up1 = pygame.transform.scale((path.get_image(32,0,16,24)),(32,48))
    self.up2 = pygame.transform.flip(self.up1,True,False)
    self.left1 = pygame.transform.scale((path.get_image(48,0,16,24)),(32,48))
    self.left2 = pygame.transform.scale((path.get_image(64,0,16,24)),(32,48))
    self.right1 = pygame.transform.flip(self.left1,True,False)
    self.right2 = pygame.transform.flip(self.left2,True,False)

    self.up_left1 = pygame.transform.scale((path.get_image(32,24,16,24)),(32,48))
    self.up_left2 = pygame.transform.scale((path.get_image(48,24,16,24)),(32,48))
    self.up_right1 = pygame.transform.flip(self.up_left1,True,False)
    self.up_right2 = pygame.transform.flip(self.up_left2,True,False)
    self.down_left1 = pygame.transform.scale((path.get_image(0,24,16,24)),(32,48))
    self.down_left2 = pygame.transform.scale((path.get_image(16,24,16,24)),(32,48))
    self.down_right1 = pygame.transform.flip(self.down_left1,True,False)
    self.down_right2 = pygame.transform.flip(self.down_left2,True,False)


    self.animObjs['walk_down']=pyganim.PygAnimation([(self.down1,.1),(self.down2,.1)])
    self.animObjs['walk_up']=pyganim.PygAnimation([(self.up1,.1),(self.up2,.1)])
    self.animObjs['walk_left']=pyganim.PygAnimation([(self.left2,.1),(self.left1,.1)])
    self.animObjs['walk_right']=pyganim.PygAnimation([(self.right2,.1),(self.right1,.1)])
    self.animObjs['walk_up_left']=pyganim.PygAnimation([(self.up_left1,.1),(self.up_left2,.1)])
    self.animObjs['walk_up_right']=pyganim.PygAnimation([(self.up_right1,.1),(self.up_right2,.1)])
    self.animObjs['walk_down_left']=pyganim.PygAnimation([(self.down_left1,.1),(self.down_left2,.1)])
    self.animObjs['walk_down_right']=pyganim.PygAnimation([(self.down_right1,.1),(self.down_right2,.1)])

    self.moveConductor = pyganim.PygConductor(self.animObjs)


def go_up(self):
    self.moveUp = True
    self.moveDown = False
    if self.moveLeft:
        self.direction = UP_LEFT
    elif self.moveRight:
        self.direction = UP_RIGHT
    if not self.moveLeft and not self.moveRight:
        self.direction = UP

def go_left(self):
    self.moveLeft = True
    self.moveRight = False
    if self.moveUp:
        self.direction = UP_LEFT
    elif self.moveDown:
        self.direction = DOWN_LEFT
    elif not self.moveUp and not self.moveDown:
        self.direction = LEFT

def go_down(self):
    self.moveDown = True
    self.moveUp = False
    if self.moveLeft:
        self.direction = DOWN_LEFT
    elif self.moveRight:
        self.direction = DOWN_RIGHT
    if not self.moveLeft and not self.moveRight:
        self.direction = DOWN

def go_right(self):
    self.moveRight=True
    self.moveLeft = False
    if self.moveUp and self.moveRight:
        self.direction = UP_RIGHT
    elif self.moveDown and self.moveRight:
        self.direction = DOWN_RIGHT
    elif not self.moveUp and not self.moveDown:
        self.direction = RIGHT


def stop_up(self):
    self.moveUp = False
    if self.moveLeft:
        self.direction = LEFT
    if self.moveRight:
        self.direction = RIGHT

def stop_left(self):
    self.moveLeft = False
    if self.moveUp:
        self.direction = UP
    if self.moveDown:
        self.direction = DOWN

def stop_down(self):
    self.moveDown = False
    if self.moveLeft:
        self.direction = LEFT
    if self.moveRight:
        self.direction = RIGHT

def stop_right(self):
    self.moveRight = False
    if self.moveUp:
        self.direction = UP
    if self.moveDown:
        self.direction = DOWN

def draw(self,surface):
    surface.blit(self.image,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y))
    if self.moveUp or self.moveDown or self.moveLeft or self.moveRight:
        self.moveConductor.play()
        if self.direction == UP:
            self.animObjs['walk_up'].blit(surface,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        if self.direction == DOWN:
            self.animObjs['walk_down'].blit(surface,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        if self.direction == LEFT:
            self.animObjs['walk_left'].blit(surface,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        if self.direction == RIGHT:
            self.animObjs['walk_right'].blit(surface,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        if self.direction == UP_LEFT:
            self.animObjs['walk_up_left'].blit(surface,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        if self.direction == UP_RIGHT:
            self.animObjs['walk_up_right'].blit(surface,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        if self.direction == DOWN_LEFT:
            self.animObjs['walk_down_left'].blit(surface,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        if self.direction == DOWN_RIGHT:
            self.animObjs['walk_down_right'].blit(surface,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))


    else:
        self.moveConductor.stop()
        if self.direction == UP:
            surface.blit(self.up1,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        elif self.direction == DOWN:
            surface.blit(self.down1,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        elif self.direction == LEFT:
            surface.blit(self.left1,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        elif self.direction == RIGHT:
            surface.blit(self.right1,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        elif self.direction == UP_LEFT:
            surface.blit(self.up_left1,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        elif self.direction == UP_RIGHT:
            surface.blit(self.up_right1,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        elif self.direction == DOWN_LEFT:
            surface.blit(self.down_left1,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
        elif self.direction == DOWN_RIGHT:
            surface.blit(self.down_right1,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y-36))
def update(self):
    if self.moveUp: self.rect.y-=self.rate
    if self.moveDown: self.rect.y+=self.rate
    if self.moveLeft: self.rect.x-=self.rate
    if self.moveRight: self.rect.x+=self.rate

def collision(self,dudes):
    for dude in dudes:
        if self.rect.colliderect(dude):
            if self.direction==RIGHT and self.rect.right < dude.rect.left+5:
                self.rect.x -= self.rate
            if self.direction==LEFT and self.rect.left > dude.rect.right-5:
                self.rect.x += self.rate
            if self.direction==DOWN and self.rect.bottom < dude.rect.top+5:
                self.rect.y -=self.rate
            if self.direction==UP and self.rect.top > dude.rect.bottom-5:
                self.rect.y += self.rate
            if self.direction==DOWN_RIGHT and self.rect.bottom<dude.rect.top+5 or self.direction==DOWN_RIGHT and self.rect.right<dude.rect.left+5:
                self.rect.x-=self.rate
                self.rect.y-=self.rate
            if self.direction==DOWN_LEFT and self.rect.bottom<dude.rect.top+5 or self.direction == DOWN_LEFT  and self.rect.left>dude.rect.right-5:
                self.rect.x+=self.rate
                self.rect.y-=self.rate
            if self.direction==UP_RIGHT and self.rect.top < dude.rect.bottom+5 or self.direction==UP_RIGHT and self.rect.right<dude.rect.left+5:
                self.rect.x-=self.rate
                self.rect.y+=self.rate
            if self.direction==UP_LEFT and self.rect.top < dude.rect.bottom+5 or self.direction==UP_LEFT and self.rect.left>dude.rect.right+5:
                self.rect.x+=self.rate
                self.rect.y+=self.rate

def layer(self,dudes,surface):
    for dude in dudes:
        if self.rect.bottom>dude.rect.y+5:
            dude.draw(surface)
            self.draw(surface)
        else:
            self.draw(surface)
            dude.draw(surface)
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: One thing I see off the bat here, I think you are confused on the difference between class variables and instance variables.  Also, your movement code looks quite overcomplicated.

Comment: THAT is a fair assumption. I kept running into variable accessibility issues when trying to debug my movement code so I turned everything into an instance variable! And promptly forgot about it. Thank you for bringing that up ill do some self.searching and make some edits.

Comment: @huligan27: I think he's saying the opposite of what you think he's saying: all those class variables like `moveUp` that you later may or may not shadow with instance variables are probably not a good idea; just make them instance variables. (Yes, you can use a class variable as a default value for an instance variable of the same name, but unless you want to be able to change the defaults at runtime, that's usually considered more confusing than helpful.)

Comment: @abarnert shoot! Okay. I understand a but of what you're saying but I obviously have a lot more studying to do. Thank you so much for your response!